# How to hide components by selecting a new value on h:selectOneMenu?

Tags: jsf-2

I have a page with a `h:selectOneMenu`, and I want to hide a `dataTable` when I choose a new value on the `h:selectOneMenu` while some bean attribute values update. I'm trying diferent things, and I'm able to hide the `dataTable` by reloading the page. I have tried this using some JavaScript code, on `onsomething` attributes. In that case, those bean attribute values disapear although I use `t:saveState` (and I also need the *view* scope for the bean).

Here is a little example to clarify this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="list" value="#{Bean.id}">       
    <f:selectItems value="#{Bean.List}" var="element" itemLabel="#{element.name}" itemValue="#{element.id}"/>
    <t:saveState value="#{Bean.id}"/>
    <f:ajax listener="#{Bean.populateBean}" render=":form:period" event="change"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:selectOneMenu id="period" value="#{Bean.period}">
<f:selectItems value="#{Bean.listaPeriod}" var="period" itemLabel="#{period[1]}" itemValue="#{period[0]}"/>
     <t:saveState value="#{Bean.period}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:commandButton id="search" action="#{Bean.doSearch}"></h:commandButton>

<t:dataTable id="data" value="#{Bean.configList}" rendered="#{Bean.search}"
     <t:column>
     ...
</t:dataTable>
```

And `Bean.doSearch` changes `Bean.search` to `true`. How can I hide the `dataTable` when I choose a new value on `h:selectOneMenu id="list"`?

EDIT:

In short, the search button renders the table, and I would want to hide that table when I just choose a new value on the "list" dropdown without reloading the page. Now, the `<f:ajax>` is used only to rerender the "period" dropdown value.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hardly understandable, but if you want to kick the datatable out of your view on ajax request triggered by your dropdown, you need to enclose it in a component that's always present in the view so that HSF would know what to rerender when ajax call successfully finishes:

```
<h:panelGroup id="rerender">
    <t:dataTable rendered="#{bean.condition}" ...>
        ....
    </t:dataTable>
<h:panelGroup>
```

Of course, to get it working you should specify id of the component to be rerendered:

```
<h:selectOneMenu ...>
    ...
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.populate}" render="rerender" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Note that if both dropdown and datatable components belong to the same form, it's not necessary to specify absolute id of the latter's parent. Also note that specifying event is redundant, as it already defaults to the right one. Finally, as you're on JSF 2.x, using save state is not necessary, just bind the values of your form data to a view scoped bean.

The last thing to note is the fact that you fail to conform to the Java Naming Conventions, the thing you should correct as soon as possible.

Comment: You are right. Maybe I have complicated the question. The thing is that the search button renders the table, and I want to hide that table when I just choose a new value on the "list" dropdown without reloading the page. The `<f:ajax>` is used only to rerender the "period" dropdown value.

Comment: In this case a viable option is simply to toggle class with `display : none` on `onchange` event.

Comment: Simple. `$(#form\\:list).change(function() { if(/*condition*/) { $(#form\\:data).addClass('invisible'); } else { $(#form\\:data).removeClass('invisible'); } });`.